# How can I get rid of a Pulseaudio sink?

Tags: pulseaudio

I'm trying to remap my stereo sound to mono (due to a broken headphone), following the answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17791/can-i-downmix-stereo-audio-to-mono) but I'm getting confused by the pacmd command.

I'm using `pacmd load-module module-remap-sink` to create a new "mono" sink in my system:

```
pacmd load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=mono master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo channels=2 channel_map=mono,mono
```

However, if I run this command more than once it will create a new sink everytime. Right now, according to `pacmd list-sinks` I have already created 3 different sinks: `mono`, `mono.2` and `mono.3`.

Is there a way to undo this and remove these newly-created sinks? Right now the only way I know is to restart the computer, which is making debugging these audio issues take forever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 pactl unload-module module-remap-sink
```

Comment: I recommend to use pasystray, then you can switching between sinks via mouse. also can unload modules